# How to receive calls/messages real-time when the application is closed

Tags: android, real-time, sip, voip

I am developing a VoIP application with SIP as the signaling protocol. I have implemented the messaging and calling functions and they work when the app is in the foreground. To make the app listen to the call and message receiving when it is closed, I  created a foreground notification so that the app would always be in the foreground.

The problem is that the above method consumes a lot of power which is unacceptable. I have also noted that famous VoIP applications like WhatsApp and Signal are not using foreground notifications but, they manage to inform us about incoming calls/messages no matter the app is closed. I wonder how to achieve the same functionality. Could anybody please point me in the right direction?

Comment: WhatsApp and similar apps use Push Notifications (reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) to trigger App's method when them should receive Messages or Calls.
A proper Push Notification is send to device providing informations about the event to raise and the App acts in the proper way.

The implementation depends How your foreground app is currently listening for incoming calls:

 - a Peer2Peer connection arrives to it and it should anwer?
 - a Poll action is done by the App to the Server that holds the voicecall until the App answers to it?

Comment: @emandt thanks for the reference. Actually, when one party dials the SIP address of another, the SIP server will resolve the receiver's IP address and indicate it on the receiver's side. When this handshaking happens, the server's interaction is pretty much over. Then there is only a peer-to-peer connection. Any thoughts?

Comment: Ok. How the App receives call information (IP address of the caller) from Server? By polling? By Push Notification? You have written about power, so I suppose By polling the server by interval....am I right?

Comment: yes of course by polling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of App should use Push Notifications (reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) that use ONE SINGLE socket connection for the whole system: each App should register itself for receiving Push, then when the Server triggers (many languages are supported by FCM with examples/tutorials) the Calling Event then a special "message" is sent to the App (providing some information about IP or whatever you want) that gets those information and acts in the proper way.

Unfortunately FCM, after few thousand notification per month, requires payment.
There are other similar online service, but those services requires a fee because they should handle many users connected at the same time and it requires hardwar and bandwidth.